# Android: how to add blush on face

Tags: android, opencv

I have worked on face detection and use http://www.milbo.users.sonic.net/stasm/ for landmark detection.
I have detected all face landmarks, now i want to add simple red blush on cheek.
I have prepared image for [image: red] and overlap on cheek, it work with white face but when i use dark face then it show me like jokar, which it not corrrent,so the blushing should be depends on skin color.if there any way to dynamic image as attached.

Can any one let me know how can i do that.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please describe the problem in more detail. I think to understand that your program kind of works, but the result doesn't look right for dark faces. So, what does it look like? Are you using alpha? if not, you will see white borders.

Comment: Can you post image examples of a blushed white face and blushed dark face?

Comment: actually i have checked on app, prefect365, which does the same.it do the same thing but with fixed color.http://screenshots.fr.sftcdn.net/fr/scrn/3332000/3332578/perfect365-01-700x467.jpg

Comment: @SameerZ. can u please help me i am doing same thing on android but cant get landmarks yet :/

Answer (score 0):

Not a precise answer, but I hope it guides you on the right direction:

Use a [Paint](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html) with a [Shader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ComposeShader.html) using [Overlay or Multiply](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html) to blend the face bitmap with the blush bitmap

Answer (score 0):

Try using `cv2.seamlessClone()` function, it has pretty good results at embedding pictures after alpha blending. I'm sure it will look much better.